# $L_{p}$ spaces with pointwise multiplication

Tags: real-analysis

Are any of the $L_{p}$ spaces Banach algebras if multiplication is defined pointwise; that is, $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=1/sqrtx,x in (0,1) and f(0)=0 is an L_1 function on [0,1] but f.f is not. So the space is not closed under multiplication.